# Algorithm / Formula on a coordinate value (x,y) to retrieve something like ((x,y),(x,y)) (Re-worded)

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, formula

**I'm trying to find a mathematical formula/function that gets 2 coordinates (x,y) and returns 4 coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2) or ((x,y), (x,y))** (however you want to format it as)

so for example, sending:
**(7,2)** would return: **3, -2, -2, 3**
instead of your basic **(7/2,1)**

**Conditions:**

- can't return something like #,0,#,0; it's just a basic slope formula (unless it's impossible and 100% needed)
- needs to reach to reach the end coordinate (what you originally sent to it) by adding the first set of values with the secondary as many times as needed
  ex: (1,2,3,4) or ((1,2),(3,4))
  var x,y = 0,0 -- Starting coordinates
  1,2 (add 1,2)
  4,6 (add 3,4)
  5,8 (add 1,2)
  8,12 (add 3,4)
  ... ETC -- Keep going until it hits the original coordinate (whatever you inputted into the function)
- Integer (whole number), positive or negative, cannot be a decimal

**The code I'm looking for:**

```lua
function calculate( x, y )
   *insert code*
   return #, #, #, #;
end
```

**Proof: (7,2) -> (3,-2,-2,3) or ((3,-2),(-2,3))**

**First set: 3,-2**
**Second set: -2,3**

```java
    0,0 (start at)
    3,-2 (add 3,-2) -- 1
    1, 1 (add -2,3) -- 2
    4,-1 (add 3,-2) -- 1
    2,2 (add -2,3) -- 2
    5,0 (add 3,-2) -- 1
    3,3 (add -2,3) -- 2
    6,1 (add 3,-2) -- 1
    4,4 (add -2,3) -- 2
    7,2 (add 3,-2) -- END
```

Code (somewhat) for the proof above:

```lua
ogX/Y - original X/Y (before you send it into the calculate function
a,b - x1,y1
c,d - x2,y2
function getPath( ogX, ogY, a,b, c,d )
    local Paths = {};
    local x, y = 0, 0;
    for index = 1, <already done>, 1 do
       if index%2 == 0 then // or have it == 1 for the flipped version
           x+=a; y+=b;
       else
           x+=c; y+=d;
       end
       if x == ogX and y == ogY then return Paths; end
    end
end
```

Basically from the code, this system is supposed to be a sort of path for a coordinate field.
If you plot the points, it should somewhat visually resemble a zig-zag. There are probably many possibilities, so what I'm looking for is one that isn't the most extreme or exaggerated line far from the original flat slope line while not also being the slope line

**Goal:**
I'm making a very large long-term project, and this project uses hexagonal cells to move around (it's like a normal coordinate graph except the Y axis is tilted a bit)
Anyways, basically in my game, there's this thing called DIRECTION (value of 1-6)
When you move non-linearly, the player can drag their mouse either to the left or right of their screen while holding down their mouse to pick which direction they want to face.
But here's the thing, choosing the direction also affects the movement of cells you walk across (which is important). (see the image, red for one side, pink for the other)
**With the usage of the 4 numbers (or 2 coordinates), depending on the direction (which is just set to a true/false for left/right)
I can either start with the first set or the second set to get the path**

I kinda already have a setup, but it isn't what I need and breaks when you get to further coordinates (the current code barely has any relation to what I'm looking for rn, aka the function above)

Pseudocode, Java, Python, Lua, just text, explanations, anything would help

[image: Coordinate Field; Left - Red, Right - Pink]

Comment: "Like a zig-zag, but the zigzag isn't too crazy" really is not a useful description. You didn't  - btw - ever mention what the 4 coordinates actually are (incremental offsets from the origin) or whether only integers are allowed. As with so many problems, this is one where when you've determined what you're really looking for, the answer is likely to be obvious.  A starting point is to work through several examples by hand to determine what "good" output looks like. Then figure out the thought process that led to them. Then capture that thought process in an algorithm.

Comment: 1. Read the text right below the zig-zag statement, I explained what it is. 2. The coordinates add up to get the same result, as previously stated, it’s like the slope formula except more uh, wonky. If you look at the example I have provided, you can see instead of adding x and y alone per step, I add them both together each cycle and swap between the two variations 3. I asked because I needed help on this, if I had tried and already figured it out, I wouldn’t have bothered making a new account to search for some assistance

Comment: What if there are several possibilities? For instance (6,2) can be reached with (2,0),(0,1) or with (3,0),(0,1) or with (3,-1),(2,2), or with (1,2),(2,-1), ...etc,...etc. Which one of those "is closest to the actual slope"? Is it minimizing the *maximum distance* of a point to the slope? The standard deviation? Maximizing the number of steps? ... Please clarify.

Comment: The specification is not clear.

Comment: As stated above, the rule is that it can’t return something like #, 0, #, 0 because at that point it’s just a normal slope. And yes, it’ll probably the lowest distance from the linear slope when comparing it. Also (1,2)(2,-1) would only work for (6,2).                                                                             (3,-1),(2,2) wouldn’t work: -> 3,-1 -> 5,1 -> 8,0 (ERROR) or 2,2 -> 5,1 -> 7,3 (ERROR)

Comment: Hi! The problem looks interesting but currently it is impossible to understand what you want. Could you try to [edit] the question to explain again, more concisely and more precisely, what you want and what's the relation between the four output coordinates and the two input coordinates? Maybe use a drawing to illustrate?